# convert utf-8 byte to string python

Tags: python, arrays, string, utf-8

I already know if I wanna encode and decode a string in 'utf-8' , i can do ...

```
string = "Kröger"

print(string.encode('utf-8'))
>> b'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'

print(b'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'.decode('utf-8')
>> Kröger
```

If I have an string `'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'` without specifying it was of `<class bytes>` (missing prefix 'b'), how will I decode this ?

Edit:

I have a tokenized list if it helps : `['K', 'r', '\\xc3\\xb6', 'g', 'e', 'r']`

Comment: Do you have `'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'` or `'Kr\\xc3\\xb6ger'`? What's the length of the string?

Comment: `'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'`, `len(striing) = 7`

Comment: This is mojibake, ie. a string decoded from bytes with the wrong codec. Specifically, Latin-1 was used to decode instead of UTF-8. You can undo the damage by en/decoding in reverse: `'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')`

Comment: @lenz, thank you. I took this word from a german word corpus.

Comment: In that case you may want to check that you correctly decode when loading the data (eg. explicitly specify `encoding='utf8'` when `open`ing a file for reading).

Comment: @lenz, makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = "Kr\xc3\xb6ger"
print(bytes(string, "raw_unicode_escape").decode("utf-8"))
```

gives

```
Kröger
```

Comment: thank you @alaniwi, i missed the `"raw_unicode_escape"`.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to encode it to bytes, then decode it from utf-8:

```
>>> s = 'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'
>>> s.encode("raw-unicode-escape")
b'Kr\xc3\xb6ger'
>>> s.encode("raw-unicode-escape").decode('u8')
'Kröger'
>>>
```